# Audio speakers doesn't work after ubuntu 20.04 installation

Tags: sound, speakers

I installed ubuntu 20.04 on a desktop pc just assembled. All looks fine but the audio speakers doesn't work. The power supply usb connection works well, and if I connect the jack on my phone I can use them without any problem; so the problem is not in the hardware. How should i proceed to identify and fix the cause of the trouble?

This are my pc specs (output of lspci):

```
emanuele@emanuele-desktop:~$ lspci
```

00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Root Complex
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:01.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse GPP Bridge
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:03.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:03.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse GPP Bridge
00:04.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:05.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:07.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:07.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to bus[E:B]
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to bus[E:B]
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 61)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 5
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 6
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 7
01:00.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43ee
01:00.1 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43eb
01:00.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43e9
02:00.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43ea
02:06.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43ea
02:07.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43ea
02:08.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43ea
02:09.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43ea
06:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
08:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G98 [GeForce 9300 GE] (rev a1)
09:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Function
0a:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Reserved SPP
0a:00.1 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Cryptographic Coprocessor PSPCPP
0a:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse USB 3.0 Host Controller
0a:00.4 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller

I've already tried to modify the file /etc/pulse/default.pa, uncommenting the following 2 lines:

```
load-module module-alsa-sink

load-module module-alsa-source device=hw:1,0
```

But after reboot nothing changes.

Comment: Have you right-clicked on the speaker symbol -> preferences and checked which output is in use?

Comment: I'm not sure about  what you're referring to @Fiximan . Are you talking about the speakers symbol on the top bar?

Comment: Yes, you should be presented a menu on right-click.

Comment: It doesn't appear to me such a menu with right click

Comment: Then via control center -> sound. What is set as output? Might as well check `alsamixer` in CLI.

Comment: The dummy output